# Partial View is not reloading using Jquery in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am created a application in MVC3 and I want to reload the partial view on button click, but partial view is not updating.

**ActionResult Method**

```
  public ActionResult CommentForPost(int postId)
    {
        var PostComments = _commentsRepository.GetCommentsByPostID(postId).Select(u => new CommentsViewModel()
       {
           CommentUserFullName = u.CommentUserFullName,
           CommenterEmailId = u.CommenterEmailId,
           CommenterSite = u.CommenterSite,

       }).ToList();

        return PartialView("PostedComments",PostComments);
    }
```

**Partial View inside Main View**

```
<div id="dvPostedComment">
@Html.Partial("PostedComments", Model.Post)
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
           var postId = $("#hdnPostId").val();

            var d = "postId=" + postId;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Comments/CommentForPost",
                data: d,
                success: function (r) {
                    $('#dvPostedComment').html(data);
                },
                complete: function () {
                    alert('hello2');
                },
                error: function (req, status, error) {
                    alert('helll3');
                }
            });
```

It always goes in error section.

Anyone can help me.

Comment: try `url: "/Comments/CommentForPost/" + postId` without `data: d,` and why do you use `POST` request for this? As per your action you should do `GET` request

Comment: in your code `success: function (r)`, but you try insert `$('#dvPostedComment').html(data);`

Comment: can you provide error message and status?

Comment: Hi Grundy... Error : Internal server error and status : prevent this page from creating additional dialogs.

Comment: are you try set breakpoint in your `CommentForPost`?

Comment: No.. I am not using any breakpoint on CommentForPost.

Grundy...This code is working for me. but only not binding the data in partial view.. have a look code below

var url = "/Comments/CommentForPost";
                   $.get(url, { "postId": PostId}, function (data) { 
                    
                       $('#dvPostedComment').html(response);
                    });

Comment: i mean - if you set break point and inside this method and it stopped on ajax call, you can see what server error cause, but if breakpoint not stopped - so you need a closer look on error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like this. I have created a small example which exactly do same which you want to achieve in your code. You can do this in two ways- using $.ajax() or using $.load(). $.load() method do same what you want.

**_InnerPartial.cshtml**

```
@model int
@{
     <h1>This is a partial view</h1>
     <h3>Your passed value=@Model</h3>         
}
```

**Controller method**

```
[HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult CallPartial(int value)
    {
        return PartialView("_InnerPartial", value);
    }
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div id="divPartial"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    AsyncAjaxCallback();
    //AsyncCallback();

});
function AsyncCallback() {
    var ctrl = $("#divPartial");
    var url = "/Example/CallPartial";

    if (url && url.length > 0) {
        ctrl.load(url, { value: 45 });
    }

}

function AsyncAjaxCallback() {
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "/Example/CallPartial",
        data: { value: 78 },
        success:function(result)
        {
            debugger;
            $("#divPartial").html(result);

        }
    });
}

</script>
```

For more details please see this link.
http://dotnet-concept.com/Article/2014/8/15/How-to-load-partial-from-jquery-in-MVC

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load "data" in the partial view div but "data" doesn't exist.
The result of ajax call is r as you have mentioned.

So try using

```
success: function (r) {
                $('#dvPostedComment').html(r);
            },
```

If you are using $.get then, use the below code:

```
$.get(url, 
     { "postId": PostId},
      function (data) { $('#dvPostedComment').html(data); 
});
```